# VARIANT data type size limit

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the size limit imposed by VARIANT data type? 16MB compressed or 16MB uncompressed?

There are two places in the documentation which are conflicting. Which is correct ? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the most common misunderstandings about variant columns ( *thanks to the repeating error in the docs*). A VARIANT can store values to a maximum size of 16 MB **uncompressed**.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant

The above page is updated recently, and you can see that the older version had the same error:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210522195216/https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html

The limitation comes from a 16 MB limit on "internal" in-memory representation, which is uncompressed. I will report the one which is misleading:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html

Comment: Yeah, so based on the archive documentation it seems like the answer is 16MB compressed. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

AFTER
The VARIANT data type imposes a 16 MB (compressed) size limit on individual rows.
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html